# Run SQLite3 in Windows7 - Not Working (unless I Run as Admin)

Tags: sqlite

I downloaded sqlite3, added sqlite3.dll, sqlite3.def and sqlite3.exe to Windows/System32. System32 is in the Windows Path. When I run SQLite3 test.db as per the Quick Start documentation from SQLite, SQLite3 is not recognized.

I also tried registering the dll but that did not work. I looked at numerous posts here and elsewhere but I cannot figure it out.

If I run sqlite3 at the cmd prompt, in System32, it is recognized. But obviously, unless I am missing something I do not want to create databases in the System32 folder. (Update)When I run a command prompt as admin, SQLite3 is recognized. Is that normal?

I guess I am viewing this as the same as Java, in the sense that once Java was added to the path I can run the Java comd from anywhere.

Conversely running in linux has been a smooth event.

Thank you,

diek

Comment: You probably already know this: if you make a change to the PATH you need to open a new terminal window to see that change.

Comment: Adam, no I did not know that. System32 was already in the path, so I am not quite tracking what you mean.

Comment: Ah, nevermind then. My comment doesn't apply. Good luck.

Comment: Deadly, I have had a crazy week at school. Nuts to be more accurate. So looking at the comment I do not see you listed above. Am I missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aha! I had the same problem today. sqlite3.exe wouldn't be recognized if it was in C:\Windows\System32 (though interestingly it would work in C:\Windows) and that location was in the path.

I solved this by "unblocking" the file as it was a downloaded file that Windows doesn't trust: Properties > General > "Unblock"

This would possibly explain why running as admin worked.

---

It is also possibly related to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911555/why-would-os-path-existsc-windows-system32-inetsrv-metaback-return-fals) of 32-bit vs. 64-bit windows, though I think it is the earlier blocking problem.

Comment: I am not certain why I am just got an e-mail notification about this.

Comment: @deadly: I have the same problem over here. I tried to "Unlock" sqlite.exe but in its properties there is nothing as "unblock" .. what should I do ?

Comment: @hashDefine Do you have admin rights? Are you running as admin? What version of Windows?

Comment: @hashDefine If it's not the "unblock" problem, have you had a look at the link I posted towards the bottom of my answer about 32-bit vs. 64-bit?